# How are the instances / datastores for different project ids comingled in GCP App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

GCP has put out several articles about how their various services work behind the scenes.

Is there any information out there illustrating how they keep projects and the data for those projects segregated?

Is my data stored on separate machines from other GCP customers? or is it the same machines with some kind of multi-tenancy implemented (like this article they have where they explain how i could implement multi-tenancy within my own datastore project https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore is a Non-SQL database, built on Megastore, which in turn builds on Bigtable. Datastore is essentially a layer on top of Bigtable that adds query semantics, transactions, and index management (a DBMS).

Perhaps [this](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Google+Cloud+Datastore) is interesting for you to know more about the internal of Google Cloud Datastore. Also, [here](https://www.slideshare.net/enakai/google-cloud-datastore-insideout) you can find a further explanation on Megastore, from which most of Datastore is part of. The information on those slides can be found in this [public paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36971.pdf).

Long story short: no, your data is not stored in a separate machine from other Google Cloud Platform users, as well as your data may reside in different physical machines.